# PushWoosh Xamarin Forms Android exception on registration

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, pushwoosh

I've been trying to implement PushWoosh's push notifications system in my existing Xamarin Forms (PCL) project and so far, it works perfectly with iOS.
When it comes to adding it to Android, I'm facing a crash at launch despite the fact that I have followed letter by letter [the guide for Xamarin Forms for Android](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/xamarin-android-sdk).

The app simply crashes on launch due to an **Unhandled exception**.

I've had fun commenting line by line to find what caused this error and it seems it is `manager.RegisterForPushNotifications();` that executes the code responsible for that crash.

After further investigation in the debug log, it seems to be a problem with the **ShortcutBadger** being unable to resolve an intent.

I've ran the app on physical devices, fully up-to-date:

- Samsung Galaxy S4
- (Asus) Google Nexus 7

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

---

## Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.package.awesome"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="4.0"
          android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
  <!-- Badges -->
    <!-- Common -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

    <!-- Apex -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"/>

    <!-- Samsung -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />

    <!-- Sony -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />

    <!-- HTC -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />

    <!-- Solid -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"/>

    <!-- Huawei -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

    <!-- ZUK -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE"/>

    <!-- OPPO -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

    <!-- EvMe -->
    <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE"/>
  <!-- /Badges -->

  <!-- Location tracking -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

  <!-- Boot permission for rescheduling local notifications and location tracking -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

  <!-- GCM Part -->
  <permission android:name="com.package.awesome.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
              android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.package.awesome.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

  <application android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="8487000" />
    <meta-data android:name="PW_APPID"
               android:value="A1B2C-3D4E5" />
    <meta-data android:name="PW_PROJECT_ID"
               android:value="awesome-app" />

    <!-- GCM Part -->
    <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.package.awesome" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

## MainActivity.cs:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Pushwoosh;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Util;

namespace Project.Droid
{
    class LocalMessageBroadcastReceiver : BasePushMessageReceiver
    {
        public MainActivity activity { get; set; }

        protected override void OnMessageReceive(Intent intent)
        {
            activity.doOnMessageReceive(intent.GetStringExtra(BasePushMessageReceiver.JsonDataKey));
        }
    }

    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "com.package.awesome.MESSAGE" }, Categories = new string[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" })]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        LocalMessageBroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App());

            mMessageReceiver = new LocalMessageBroadcastReceiver();
            mMessageReceiver.activity = this;

            registerReceivers();

            PushManager manager = PushManager.GetInstance(this);
            manager.OnStartup(this);

            // Register for push!
            manager.RegisterForPushNotifications();

            // Reset application icon badge number
            manager.BadgeNumber = 0;

            checkMessage(Intent);
        }

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            checkMessage(intent);
        }

        public void checkMessage(Intent intent)
        {
            if (null != intent)
            {
                if (intent.HasExtra(PushManager.PushReceiveEvent))
                {
                    doOnMessageReceive(intent.Extras.GetString(PushManager.PushReceiveEvent));
                }

                resetIntentValues();
            }
        }

        public void doOnMessageReceive(String message)
        {
            // hadle push open here
            Log.Debug("PushwooshSample", "Push opened: " + message);
        }

        private void resetIntentValues()
        {
            Intent mainAppIntent = Intent;

            if (mainAppIntent.HasExtra(PushManager.PushReceiveEvent))
            {
                mainAppIntent.RemoveExtra(PushManager.PushReceiveEvent);
            }
            else if (mainAppIntent.HasExtra(PushManager.RegisterEvent))
            {
                mainAppIntent.RemoveExtra(PushManager.RegisterEvent);
            }
            else if (mainAppIntent.HasExtra(PushManager.UnregisterEvent))
            {
                mainAppIntent.RemoveExtra(PushManager.UnregisterEvent);
            }
            else if (mainAppIntent.HasExtra(PushManager.RegisterErrorEvent))
            {
                mainAppIntent.RemoveExtra(PushManager.RegisterErrorEvent);
            }
            else if (mainAppIntent.HasExtra(PushManager.UnregisterErrorEvent))
            {
                mainAppIntent.RemoveExtra(PushManager.UnregisterErrorEvent);
            }

            Intent = mainAppIntent;
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            registerReceivers();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();

            unregisterReceivers();
        }

        public void registerReceivers()
        {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(PackageName + ".action.PUSH_MESSAGE_RECEIVE");
            RegisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver, intentFilter);
        }

        public void unregisterReceivers()
        {
            UnregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

## Crash log:

```
07-31 10:12:09.182 D/Pushwoosh(29231): [RequestManager] Try To send: getInApps
07-31 10:12:09.185 V/Pushwoosh(29231): [GCMRegistrationService] Intent action = com.pushwoosh.gcm.intent.REGISTER
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231): [ShortcutBadger] Unable to execute badge
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231): com.pushwoosh.thirdparty.a.b: Unable to execute badge
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at com.pushwoosh.thirdparty.a.c.b(Unknown Source)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at com.pushwoosh.thirdparty.a.c.a(Unknown Source)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at com.pushwoosh.internal.PushManagerImpl$2.run(Unknown Source)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231): Caused by: com.pushwoosh.thirdparty.a.b: unable to resolve intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE (has extras) }
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  at com.pushwoosh.thirdparty.a.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
07-31 10:12:09.190 E/Pushwoosh(29231):  ... 10 more
```

---

Please note that I've renamed the project name, package, PushWoosh app ID and FCM app ID for confidentiality purposes.

Comment: Bug: https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/90

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I've already read this post and as they say at the end, this issue was closed with no valid solution.

Comment: Its open source, you can always modify the source to work with the launcher that your are using. The core issue is that the launcher that you are using does not have an `android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE` intent defined

Comment: I get it, and once again thank you for responding so fast. The main problem I have is that I'm developing a Xamarin project, using a package management system (NuGet) and thus, I'd have to remove all the packages linked to the one calling this feature and then recode and inject them manually in my solution. I doubt I'd have the necessary knowledge to do that nor the time.

Comment: which version of pushwoosh package are you using?

Comment: Hi Mike, I&#39;m using the latest stable version available for Xamarin.Android on NuGet, which is 4.12.2. Is there any similar report with this or older versions?
Edit: they don't seem to provide an older version on NuGet so I couldn't test another.

Comment: ok this is all about nuget packages, I have just gone through exactly the same problem

Comment: you need to update the googleplayservices.gcm package to v42

Comment: version number!!
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs7qs.png

Comment: So glad to see I'm not alone! Thanks for the idea, I'll try it tomorrow at work and provide a feedback. 

Comment: no you are not!!! I have just spent the last 2 days figuring this out, it will work, you just need to make sure you get the latest (prerelease) versions of Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 and googleplayservices.gcm. There is a post in stackoverflow which I cant find now that put me on the right track. Once I had updated the packages everything started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by updating the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm` dependency to the latest version `42.1021.1` while mine was `29.x.x`.

As Mike said in the comments, I had to make sure that everything is up-to-date since PushWoosh does not require a high version of critical dependencies such as Google Play Services while they could potentially crash the app if obsolete. They should be more restrictive on that point !